# GWT - how to set an entry point method for all incomming requests in RPC servelet

Tags: java, web-services, gwt

I have a RemoteServiceServlet class implements several services (methods).
All the methods need to check the session and get the corresponding user info before doing anything. Since the class have more than 20 service methods, doing so in every service is a nightmare. Is there a way to run some session checking method automatically for all the incoming requests? Or how can I solve this problem?

Here is an example pseudo-code for my situation.

```
public class OnboardingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements OnboardingService {

    private String checkSessionAndGetUser(){...}

    public void service1(){
       // check session
       // get user and do something based on the user data
    }

    public void service2(){
       // check session
       // get user and do something based on the user data
    }

    public void service3(){
       // check session
       // get user and do something based on the user data
    }

    ...

    public void service20(){
       // check session
       // get user and do something based on the user data
    }

}
```

As you can see, service1, service2, ..., service 20 all need to get the user info based on the session, but I do not want to repeat writing the code for every service. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest to override `processCall(RPCRequest rpcRequest)`

```
@Override
public String processCall(RPCRequest rpcRequest) throws SerializationException {
    //your checks here, in case of error:
    //return RPC.encodeResponseForFailedRequest(null, new Exception("Invalid session"));
  // note that you'll have to use a serializable exception type here.

    return super.processCall(rpcRequest);
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but I am not able to return an Exception as you sugguested "return RPC.encodeResponseForFailedRequest(null, new Exception("Invalid session"));"  It complains that the Exception is not serilizable. Have you tried it? @ArcTanH

Comment: Yes, you're right, GWT complains about a non serializable exception, even if you make it serializable with annotations, serialVersionUID and such. How about you 'reuse' SerializationException with a custom message?

Comment: OK， I solved this issue. I had to extend IsSerializable instead of Serilizable.

Answer (score 1):

`RemoteServletServlet`'s `doPost` is `final`, but not `service`, so you can put your code there.

…or use a servlet filter.

This will however be done outside the "RPC" (before the request is even decoded), so response cannot just be a "throw exception and have it passed to `onFailure` on client side".
For that, you'll have to either use aspect-oriented programming (such as AspectJ) to "inject" code into all your methods, or call an init method at the beginning of each method (you'll keep repeating the code, but that could possibly be reduced to a one-liner).

Comment: Would you be able to post a simple example using AspectJ to do this? I couldn't find any comprehensive example. Ideally, this should be annotation based.